# Couldn't resolve resource @layout/date_picker_selected_date

Tags: android, rendering

I am building an application in Android Studio, which requires the use of date-picker. But when I am using date-picker in the layout file, I am getting the following rendering error:

> Couldn't resolve resource @layout/date_picker_selected_date   Failed
>   to parse file C:\Users\Arnab
>   PC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-21\data\res\layout\date_picker_holo.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and temporarily solved it by this way: File → Invalidate caches / Restart... → Invalidate and Restart.

If it couldn't solve your problem. You should do other ways such as creating a button and a datepickerdialog will be shown after click on the button.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem happend to me. This is an issued raised in API 21. You can try drop your API down to 19 and my problem disappeared.

See also here:[Issue 151326:@code.google](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=151326)